# Why is this class which inherits from ActiveRecord::Base incapable of class_eval ing scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, class-eval

Note: I know what I'm doing here is probably stupid but I'm not even necessarily going to use this code I'm just curious at this point.

I'm trying to dynamically add an empty Rails scope to a class in the event a specific method is missing on the class

This documentation in particular seems to suggest this should be possible: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

```
module Mod
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      if m.match? /method/
        klass = class << self; self; end

        klass.class_eval { scope :method, -> {} }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

klass is correctly set to the class here however trying to eval the creation of the scope fails with `undefined method 'scope' for #<Class:0x0000560e35d2eb48>` however when I call `klass.ancestors` I can confirm that klass is inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base` and should have scope.

Any ideas why I can't `class_eval` `scope` here

Comment: what happen if you use `self` instead of  `kclass`: `self.class_eval { scope: method, -> {} }`

Comment: One problem with the code is that you have a name clash with [`Object#method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#method-i-method) which is used to instrospect methods and which you should not clobber.

Comment: @max I just switched out the method name becuase I like to make SO posts as generic as possible. The real method has a valid name. but, good catch

Comment: @LamPhan this was the correct answer. If you'd like to suggest it as an official answer I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume that there's a class `Person < ActiveRecord::Base` that will include your module `Mod`.
In Ruby, inheritant hierarchy look like below (the horizontal superclass chain):

```
  Class                   Class
    |                       |
  Person -superclass->  ActiveRecord::Base
```

So that `Person.class` will not return `ActiveRecord::Base` but `Class:Person` (the vertical chain above), that mean your code `kclass = class << self; self; end` actually return `Person.class` which is `Class:Person` - a Class object that has not anything relative to ActiveRecord::Base - so it'll not `respond_to? :scope`

```rb
module Mod
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    # override Person#method_missing
    def method_missing(m, *args, &block)
      # anytime call Person.a_method_that_not_be_defined
      puts self # Person
      kclass = class << self; self; end # <--- Class:Person
```

So in this case, you should use `self.class_eval` instead of `kclass.class_eval`.